# Why does this happen to my model when I apply the cloth simulation?

Tags: modeling, rigging, physics, eevee-render-engine, cloth-simulation

[image] When I apply cloth simulation, for some reason the clothing itself gets moved down under the grid map. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does it get moved or is it falling down when you press Space? If it falls then it falls because cloth sim is using gravity and your character has no collisions

Comment: no, like in an instant

Comment: and is your scene at frame 0/1? If yes then it would be better to share your file

Comment: how do I share my file? also it's around frame 150

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ use this website to share it directly to this question. Also, what happens if you go to frame 0 then?

Comment: actually you're right, I started at frame 0 but when it played on, it fell down

Comment: So I was right, the only reason why is your mesh down is because it fell down, due to either not having a good set (cloth is physics-based, so gravity is a thing you need to think about), If you just went from frame 0 to frame 150 it can make some weird stuff as well, it need to run, bake, and calculate each frame, not jump from 0 to 150... Also entering edit mode can move your mesh in different place if physics are used on that object (you will need to bake/run animation again after edit)